# How to use filename instead of an external link to import CSV data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to import a file without using an external link to import CSV data into Google Sheets via AppsScript, a few attempts will come to nothing.

```
function myFunction() {
  function importData()
  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var url = 'https://your-data-source.csv';
    var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(text);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }
  }
  importData();
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  function importData()
  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var fileName = 'TEST.csv';
    var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileName).getContentText();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(text);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }
  }
  importData();
}
```

I tried for other attributes and also not:

```
    function myFunction() {
  function importData()
  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("RECORDS.csv")
  var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }
  }
  importData();
}
```

Log:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')

Comment: Where is the file stored?

Answer (score 2):

#### Modification points:

- From `I tried for other attributes and also not:` and your bottom script and `Log: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')`, I guessed that your file of `RECORDS.csv` is existing in Google Drive, and `csvData` is a 2-dimensional array from `RECORDS.csv`.
- Also, I think that the reason for your error of `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')` is due to that `sheet` is null (no sheet name of "Sheet1"). So please check the sheet name again.
- In your script, `setValues` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will be high.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("RECORDS.csv")
  var csv = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // or ss.getSheetByName('### valid sheet name ###');
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

- In this modification, the 1st tab is used with `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]`.
- If you want to use the specific sheet by the sheet name, please use the valid sheet name to `ss.getSheetByName('### valid sheet name ###')`.